# How to get user id using email id in teams using python

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm creating a bot to notify a user after an action has been done. Where i'm able to get my details using the below(screenshot) code.

[image: User details]

Now in order to send a message to a user through a bot i would need his/her `ID` before hand to send a notification like in the above case i'm able to extract my info as i'm already logged in Teams. Unfortunately alphanumeric `ID` is very difficult to use and needs to be there before requesting and sending the notification.

Below is the JSON result if the `ID` is already known.

```
Response body
{
    "id": "29:1GcS4EyB_oSI8A88XmWBN7NJFyMqe3QGnJdgLfFGkJnVelzRGos0bPbpsfJjcbAD22bmKc4GMbrY2g4JDrrA8vM06X1-cHHle4zOE6U4ttcc",
    "objectId": "9d3e08f9-a7ae-43aa-a4d3-de3f319a8a9c",
    "givenName": "Larry",
    "surname": "Brown",
    "email": "Larry.Brown@fabrikam.com",
    "userPrincipalName": "labrown@fabrikam.com",
    "tenantId":"72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47", 
    "userRole":"user"
}
```

How i can get the unique ID of the user by using email id so that i can send a personal message to him/her using bot.

Comment: Usually its the other way around, where someone wants to try to get the ID first and the users email address next... Being said that the above is interesting, let me see what i find

Comment: Basically i want to send a notification to 'xyz' person and only information which i have is user email id. It is for end user who has his/her manager email id not an alphanumeric ID.

Comment: Can you please include hyperlinks to the documentation you've been following? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney I’m following this doc. which is related to sending proactive message to users . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=python#get-the-user-id-or-teamchannel-id

Comment: @Vin - Is Wajeed's answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I not 100% sure because as per the documentation it is still asking for user-id to be there to check the details. If you go through this section it is asking for User Id .(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#enable-proactive-app-installation-and-messaging)

Comment: @Vin - You can get the user's AAD Id using email Id - 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[YourEmailId]. This Id can be used to [determine if App Is installed for recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-determine-whether-your-bot-is-currently-installed-for-a-message-recipient). Note: When your app is installed for the user, the bot will receive a `conversationUpdate` event notification that will contain the necessary information to send the proactive message.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Oh ok now i got your point let me try that also as I have reached on this site https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer where i'm doing my testing of different scenarios. Thanks for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option to [fetch conversationChatId to send proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-retrieve-the-conversation-chatid).

Before you fetch the conversation Id, you should check whether your bot is currently installed for a message recipient or not.

*Note:* [Installation of app via Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-install-your-app) triggers conversation update event for Bot.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the right direction now i can try different scenarios. Cheers

Comment: one quick question suppose first time when there is no bot/app installed for the user in that case i will get the conversation update after installation, but what about the second time when the app is already installed then how i can send the notification to a specific user.

Comment: Installation of app via Graph API triggers conversation update event for Bot. Updated my answer with note.

Comment: I got you point but what if i have already installed the app. Next time when i have to again send a message to the same user then how i will get the id?

Comment: When you get the conversation update event, you need to save the information about the user in backend. This could be in form of mapping between emaiId=> conversationDetails.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped so that others can discover it.